# Python Searching list entry for specific part

Tags: python, list, substring

I was just wondering if there is an easier way to search a list entry for a specific part of the string. I am receiving forecast data from a Weather API and am trying to sort the info into variable to display.in this example all i want is the weather status.

Line 1: Prints the first list entry

Line 2: prints the index number of first character of 'status='

Line 3: puts the list entry into a string

Line 4: prints the trimmed string with only the info i want

```
print lst[0]
print int(str(lst[0]).find("status="))
day1 = str(lst[0])
print day1[int(str(lst[0]).find("status="))+7:-1]
```

Output:

```
<pyowm.webapi25.weather.Weather - reference time=2017-03-16 02:00:00+00, status=Rain>
73
Rain
```

Comment: You could always split it on `,` and extract the appropriate index value of where you object would be? If the format is known and you're sure it doesn't vary to much? `lst[0].split(',')[1]` and do `lst[0].split(',')[1].strip('<>,;\\ ')` to clean it up.

Comment: Doesn't seem too bad.. The conversion to `str` is probably not needed and if you are to assign a variable (`day1`) you might as well use it as much as possible (move it one line up and replace all upcoming instances of `lst[0]`).

Comment: a shorter-code alternative would be `lst[0].rstrip('>').split(',')[-1].replace(' status=', '')`

Answer (score 0):

```
str_dump = lst[0]
if "status" in str_dump:
    print str_dump[str_dump.index("status")+7:]
```

if that status statement is not in the last then you have to split it EX.

```
str_dump = lst[0]
if "status" in str_dump:
    print (a[a.index("status")+7:]).split(' ')[0]
```